# Why is only the second value entered printed?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char wunit[2]; // weight unit
    char hunit[2]; // height unit

    double weight, height;

    printf("Enter the body weight: ");
    scanf("%lf%s", &weight, &wunit); // input weight and unit eg. 150lb

    printf("Enter the height: "); 
    scanf("%lf%s", &height, &hunit); // input height and unit eg. 5.65 ft

    printf("The height unit: %s\n", hunit);
    printf("The weight unit: %s", wunit);

    return 0;
}
```

This code only prints out the height unit, and not the weight unit. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Quick question. If you're writing C code, why did you tag it C++?

Comment: `printf` expects strings output with `%s` to be null-terminated. Increase the length of the arrays to at least 3, and use `scanf("%2s", hunit)` to tell `scanf` not to read more than two characters.

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh are the safety functions standardized? I thought they were only a VC++ thing... learn something new I guess.

Comment: @Craig I'm a C++ programmer, not C, sorry for the mistake! I've edited my comment to use the standard `scanf` rather than recommend `scanf_s`. Thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyBurleigh no worries. i was getting excited there for a minute. I actually like those apis a lot.. Now you've crushed my aspirations =( dammit!

Comment: Why aren't you printing a `\n` after the weight?

Comment: @KeithThompson That is his issue. You should post that as the answer.

Comment: @James: How do you know that's his issue? (And JesperE already posted that as an answer.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Missed the posted answer. My bad.

Comment: @James: Ok, but again, I'm curious how you concluded that that's the problem. On many systems, the final `printf` will simply print the message without a trailing newline.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes it should flush when the program exits but if the user has a long terminal prompt they may not notice that it really did print out. It is an easy thing to over look for a new programmer and would be the first thing to suggest they try since the OP said it is not printing the "weight unit". That said I misread that to mean it did not print out the entire line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't allowing much space for those two strings: only 2 `char` for each. Note that C strings also require space for a null-terminating character to mark the end of the string.

With the null-terminating character, your two strings can each only properly hold a single character. When you input e.g. "lb" and "ft", you're using data outside the bounds of your arrays. Change the size of your arrays to (at least) 3, and see if the code prints out both units correctly:

```
char wunit[3]; // weight unit
char hunit[3]; // height unit
```

Your code works fine for me with larger arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `\n` in the last `printf()` statement, and since stdout is probably buffered, it is only written to the screen at end-of-line.

Comment: Yours is the only one that answered the question asked ... but you ought to address the other bugs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using `%s` in `scanf`is always a bad idea, for the same reason that `gets` is always a bad idea.  You must specify a fixed buffer size; yours, of 2, is absurdly small, but more generally, you cannot control how many characters will be in the input stream, so your program will be susceptible to buffer overflow.

Some ways to fix this:

- Prefix `%s` with some length, i.e. "`%2s`".  This will put a maximum length on the amount of characters copied.
- Use `fgets` to read the whole line into a string buffer (with some arbitrary maximum), then you have some bounds to the value you wish to read with `%s`.  You can even use `sscanf` to do it.
- Use something like `readline` which will allocate arbitrary amounts of characters to read the line.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to but a two character string inside a 2 character array.
Strings should always end with '\0', so you should do:

```
char wunit[3]; // weight unit
char hunit[3]; // height unit
```

For example, the wunit array would have: ['l', 'b', 0]